# Link displacement

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I have some links on a page.
When I click (tap) one of these links, the gray box which shows where I tap is misplaced. It seems that the link is rendered higher than it should.

Is this a known Mobile Safari issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have some links on a page"? Is it an HTML file you're displaying in Safari, or have you published it yourself, or is it on a site you have no control over? In any case, in what context are you viewing these links?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your web page's CSS and/or how the Webkit rendering engine handles your page's CSS. In either case, I'd recommend this question be on ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you give an example of a web page? (so that others can test it out as well)

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

Comment: (ok don't hit return when commenting). The page is built up using soap as is a site where you have to pay for a subscription. I'm sorry but I cannot spread log in credetials for the site. I was wondering if anyone have have similar problems. You can see a image here: http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/7691/safarilinkoffseterrorwi.png